# Create Node Module based off of Cordova Plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently developing an app where a requirement is to open another or take you to the respective store to download if the app is not on the device. I am using Ionic 3 and Angular 4.

For the opening of the app, I went to use Ionic's Native InAppBrowser and this works great for both iOS and Android for apps like Twitter and Facebook. It also works great for for the current app I am trying to open on iOS. However, on android, I get intent errors. I was able to get around this by opening the app natively, which involved me opening up the transpiled code in InAppBrowser and putting the native code in there. This can be a solution, but I don't like it since that means that if InAppBrowser were to ever update, I would have to remember to re add my code.

This gave me the idea to write my own plugin. I followed a this guide to create a plugin: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/
It was great to follow, except when testing the plugin. I have no idea on how to reference the plugin in Angular. I would like to create a node module that works with my plugin so that I can test properly. I've tried looking at the node modules that are current exporting a plugin, but I have not been able to siff through the code to find out what I need specifically.

I was hoping someone could show me the proper way to create a plugin and node module for angular, sort of what Ionic does with their native code.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean with creating your own `node_module` but this is how you use a custom cordova-plugin in Ionic (I'm using the In-App-Browser plugin as an example here):

```
declare var NameOfTheJsModule // tell typescript that this js-module exists
```

You can find the name of the js-module in plugin.xml of the plugin under the name property:

```
<js-module src="www/inappbrowser.js" name="inappbrowser">
  ...
</js-module>
```

so in this case:

```
delcare var inappbrowser;
```

and to use it:

```
this.inappbrowser.show();
```

What Ionic does with `ionic-native` is wrapping the API of a plugin into a typescript class to provide you with types (which makes using plugins easier in many cases) and to make Angular change-detection work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

So in this case, will the code run when I use ionic serve, or will it only work when I build a platform?

I tried the code above and it tells me it is undefined when running with ionic serve.

Comment: Well, cordova is not available when you run `ionic serve` so no the plugin will not be available. To use your plugin in the browser you have to add the browser platform: `ionic cordova platform add browser` and run: `ionic cordova run browser`. You also have to specify the browser platform in your `plugin.xml`.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I was able to successfully create a cordova plugin and use it. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Great! No problem, always glad to help!